# show warning when login failed

Tags: php, html, authentication

I have a HTML code inside my home page that is for user login.
Also, its PHP code is written inside another page.
If the username and password are entered correctly, it will go to the admin page, But if something goes wrong, it goes to the login.php page.

HTML Code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content modal-info">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body real-spa">
                <div class="login-grids">
                    <div class="login">
                        <div class="login-left">
                            <form action="index/login.php" method="post">
                                <h3>login</h3>
                                <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username">
                                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password">
                                <h4><a href="#">forgot password</a> / <a href="#">create new password</a></h4>
                                <div class="single-bottom">
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="brand" value="">
                                    <label for="brand"><span></span>remember me</label>
                                </div>
                                <input type="submit" name="login" value="login">
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

PHP Code:

```
if (isset($username)){
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `password` = '$password'");

    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    // var_dump($password == $row['password']);die();
        if ($username == $row['username'] && $password == $row['password']){
            header( "Location: ../admin/admin.php");
        }else{
            header("Location: ../index.php?login=0");
        }
    }
}
```

How can an error message be displayed on the same page below the fields when the wrong username and password are entered?

Comment: “If something goes wrong, it goes to the login.php-page” but your code says index.php. also: is the html-code actually the content of your index.php? And by the way: Never ever ever under no circumstances, not even in playground-projects, save passwords in plaintext (hint: bcrypt). You should also escape your input and/or use prepared statements, with this sql-code you can easily sql-inject by suffixing the username e.g. with `' --`. Your second check doesn't make it better because its not typesave.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($username)){
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `password` = '$password'");

while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
// var_dump($password == $row['password']);die();
    if ($username == $row['username'] && $password == $row['password']){
        header( "Location: ../admin/admin.php");
    }else{
        // if login failed
        echo "Login failed";
    }
}
```

I just added echo. Did you checked?

Comment: Don't forget to escape $username and $password before using them in the query.

Answer (score -2):

You can write some logic on querystring ?login=0 . For example put this block of code  where you want the message appears:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['login'])) {
   //You may also check if it equals 0 then
   echo "Login failed";
}
?>
```